# AngularJS Smart Table Filter and pagination is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, smart-table

My smart table, i dont know why pagination and filter are not working. Any help will be appreciated. Checkout the complete plunker here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/urszFqto8xM6OCy9n1Fo?p=preview

View

```
<table st-table="dataList" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Total Goods</th>
          <th>Grand Total</th>
          <th>Merchant ID</th>
          <th>Order Id</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <th colspan="3"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text"/></th>
            </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
          <td>{{data.goods_total}}</td>
          <td>{{data.grand_total}}</td>
          <td>{{data.m_id}}</td>
          <td>{{data.order_id}}</td>
          <td>{{data.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>
```

controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table','sampleService'])
.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope','$http','demoService', function ($scope,$http,sampleService) {

   console.log("in controller");
    $scope.dataList = [];
    $scope.itemsByPage = 5;
    sampleService.getData().success(function(data){
            $scope.dataList = data.objects;
            console.log("data is" +$scope.dataList);
        })
}]);
```

Comment: Following error is coming on servive, Status Code:503 Service Unavailable, check in netwroks tab

Comment: @saikumar : the data is getting populated there is no error in that. Why pagination and filtering is not working , this i am not able to get. I am able to see the data in the table.

Comment: I would look into this.  Your data is dynamically being loaded via Ajax I assume https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/238